# Removing or reset contributor from github.com?

Tags: git, github, git-rewrite-history

I have done several commits with a wrong user, so I have renamed that commits with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="user2@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="user1"
CORRECT_EMAIL="user1@example.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags

git push --force --tags origin HEAD:master
```

After that, I check https://github.com/MIUSER/MYREPO/commits/master and I can see that It have worked: Author have been correctly change. Also, I check https://github.com/MIUSER/MYREPO/graphs/contributors and I see that the wrong author has disappeared.

But when I go to https://github.com/MIUSER/MYREPO and check the "Contributors" section in the right column I can still see the wrong author.

What can I do in order to fix that?

Comment: I think you've done everything you can do from the git side of things. It's possible that Github caches some information on that page and time will fix it. If it doesn't, you'll have to look at other options with GitHub specifically. In other words: this is one of the rare git questions where the [tag:github] tag is actually appropriate, because it's not purely about git.